# How do I show the connecting homomorphism is well defined?

Tags: de-rham-cohomology

Is the connecting homomorphism

$
d^* : H^k(\mathcal C) \to H^{k+1}(\mathcal A)
$
well defined?

$0 \to \mathcal A \to \mathcal B \to \mathcal C \to 0$ is short exact.

$\mathcal A$, $ \mathcal C$ are cochain complexes, while
$H^k(\mathcal X) = \frac{\ker(d^\mathcal X_k)}{\text{image}(d^\mathcal X_{k-1})}$

I thought that the way to go is to show that, given $c, c' \in [c]\in H^k(\mathcal C), c, c' \in C_k$ then
$d*[c-c'] = 0$.

Since $j$ is onto, $c-c' = j(b)-j(b') = j(b-b')$, with $b, b' \in B_k$.
Then  $0 = d(c-c') = j(db-db')$. So $db-db'\in \ker(j) = \text{image}(i)$, which is one-to-one. There is a unique $a^* \in A^{k+1}$ such that $i(a^*) = db-db'$. If only I could show that $(b-b') = d(b''), b'' \in B_{k-1}$ I could conclude that $di(a*) = id(a*) = 0 \iff da^* = 0 \iff a^* \in \text{image}(d^{\mathcal A}_{k})$.

Is that correct?